# Overlap css pushing element

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i have a problem with overlap this is a full header with a background image and i have some content also a button but is pushing out of header,how i can fix this?
What i am trying to do is full header with a background but i am stuck here.
Thank you for help[Look what is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAy9R.png)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
h1{
  margin:0;
}

.wrap{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:950px;
  height:100%;
}
header {
    background:url("https://unsplash.com/@aidanjjmeyer?photo=ckrUhWyTde8");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
.text{
   text-align: Center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;

}
.menu{
  padding-top:30px;
}
.bar1 , .bar2 , .bar3{
  width:35px;
  height:3px;
  background-color:#262626;
  margin:6px 0;
}
.btn{
  border:1px solid aqua;
  background:transparent;
  font-size:25px;
  color:white;
  outline:none;
}
#about{
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
  <title>Journal</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h1>Brooke Journalist</h1>
        <button class="btn">Contact</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
<section id="about">

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want the button?

Comment: what is  problem, exactly??

Comment: Looks totally fine to me in: https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/3w27cm7c/1/ I took your code and cleaned it up just a little bit (formatting wise). You might have some other CSS affecting it.

Comment: I would really like to help you. However, I don't understand what is wrong. Could you add some information?